Replace newlines with \n
I’m making forum and JSON can't save with newlines. I can't show code (security reasons).
I want to replace all newlines from textarea to \n so later I’ll format them.
I tried:
content.value.replace(/\r?\n/g, "\n");

But still saved with newline.

You need to escape it. "\\n"

@Zac Anger not works... Maybe i did something wrong

What does “JSON can’t save with newlines” mean?

Strings are immutable in JavaScript, meaning that once they have been assigned, their value cannot be changed.  You should assign your current expression back to the original string, the latter on the LHS:
content.value = content.value.replace(/\r\n/g, "\n");

Also note that there is no point in replacing on \r?\n, as if the \r be not present, you would just be replacing \n with itself (a no-op).

I thought so too. "Replace newline character with newline character". Didn’t make much sense to me.
